# Vaex error: AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, vaex

I am using vaex in python and am having a hard time printing values of a column. If I create a dataframe from local data it works:

```
df = vaex.from_arrays(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 3, 4])
df['inside'] = df.geo.inside_polygon(df2['x'], df2['y'], px, py)
print('col values: ' + str(df['inside'].values))
```

When I try to print a column from a dataframe (from a file with 14 million lines) stored as a global variable, I get the error `AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray' object has no attribute 'dtype'` I am able to print the dataframe with:

```
print('v: ' + str(df))
```

Both ways the object type of df is `<class 'vaex.dataframe.DataFrameLocal'>`

Why is this error occuring when I load from a file and not when I create data locally?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're referencing a `df2` in your code.

This runs fine for me with vaex 4.8.0

```
import vaex
import numpy as np

px = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5])
py = np.array([2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5])
df = vaex.from_arrays(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 3, 4])
df['inside'] = df.geo.inside_polygon(df['x'], df['y'], px, py)
print('col values: ' + str(df['inside'].values))
```